# Compound sentence and politeness

Tags: grammar, politeness

I have a sentence "*I study because I'm a student*":

> 私は学生だから私は勉強する

Can I replace the だ in だから with です to make it more polite? In the following way:

> 私は学生ですから私は勉強する

Please correct me if my original sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important verb is the one at the end. If you replace だ with です but don't change する to します, you haven't really gained any politeness; it's just unnatural.

The two below are okay, though. The second is the most polite, best for talking to strangers and people who outrank you socially. The first is good for senpai, who are often basically friends who are older than you. (Note that Japanese people never use the word "friend" (友達) to describe someone more than a year or so older than them, in my experience.)

> 私は学生だから勉強します。
>   私は学生ですから勉強します。

(You don't need 私は more than once.)

Comment: Actually, as long as the context is clear, you don't need 私は at all. That's hard for all of us in the beginning, but you'll get used to it!

Comment: in the case of using just one  私は should i remove the second one?

Comment: You can keep either one, actually. It's up to you!